# Android Studio (Kotlin) GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter() gives 2 errors

Tags: android, gson, kotlin

I am using the [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) plugin and trying to create a [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) variable using [GsonBuilder](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html).

This used to work without problems in Java, but now in I get the two errors when trying to use [registerTypeAdapter()](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.Object-), as shown below:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, DateTimeTypeConverter()).create()
```

For the first parameter (type), I get **"name expected" error.**

[image]

For the second parameter (typeAdapter), I get "expecting an expression" error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.class` should be changed to `Date::class.java`

Maybe it will resolve your second issue as well, otherwise please post your `DateTimeTypeConverter` source code

> Class References
>
> The most basic reflection feature is getting the runtime reference to
>   a Kotlin class. To obtain the reference to a statically known Kotlin
>   class, you can use the class literal syntax:
>
> val c = MyClass::class The reference is a value of type KClass.
>
> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class
>   reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on
>   a KClass instance.

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Comment: Also you can try to use some 3rd-party libraries for Gson written in kotlin, like: https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson